# How Barcode reader works in background vb.Net

Tags: vb.net-2010

How can I make vb form work automatically in background when it reads barcode. Search for item in db and add it to datagrudview

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading, or background worker in VB.

you can read this article from dotnetperls
https://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet